# Java unit test exception expected

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I have a problem, unit test should throw an exception

```
public class MainActivityTest {
    NumberPicker warmUpSeconds;
    NumberPicker warmUpMinutes;
    NumberPicker restSeconds;
    NumberPicker restMinutes;
    NumberPicker coolDownSeconds;
    NumberPicker coolDownMinutes;
    NumberPicker workMinutes;
    NumberPicker workSeconds;
    NumberPicker rounds;
    @Test(expected = WrongTimeSetEx.class)
    public void testButtonOnClick() throws WrongTimeSetEx {
        MainActivity tested=mock(MainActivity.class);
        warmUpSeconds=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        warmUpMinutes=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        restSeconds=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        restMinutes=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        coolDownMinutes=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        coolDownSeconds=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        workMinutes=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        workSeconds=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        rounds=mock(NumberPicker.class);
        when(warmUpSeconds.getValue()).thenReturn(0);
        when(warmUpMinutes.getValue()).thenReturn(0);
        when(restMinutes.getValue()).thenReturn(0);
        when(restSeconds.getValue()).thenReturn(0);
        when(coolDownSeconds.getValue()).thenReturn(10);
        when(coolDownMinutes.getValue()).thenReturn(15);
        when(workMinutes.getValue()).thenReturn(10);
        when(workSeconds.getValue()).thenReturn(10);
        when(rounds.getValue()).thenReturn(0);
        tested.setTimes();
    }
}
```

and there is tested method

```
public void setTimes() throws WrongTimeSetEx
    {
        warmUpTime = warmUpSeconds.getValue();
        warmUpTime += 60 * warmUpMinutes.getValue();
        restTime = restSeconds.getValue();
        restTime += 60 * restMinutes.getValue();
        coolDownTime = coolDownSeconds.getValue();
        coolDownTime += 60 * coolDownMinutes.getValue();
        workTime = workSeconds.getValue();
        workTime += 60 * workMinutes.getValue();
        roundsNumber = rounds.getValue();
        String communicate="";
        if(restTime==0) //check if times are correct and make sense
            communicate+="No time set for Rest Time!<br>\n";
        if(workTime==0)
            communicate+="No time set for Work Time!<br>\n";
        if(roundsNumber==0)
            communicate+="No rounds number is set!<br>\n";
        if(!communicate.isEmpty())
            throw new WrongTimeSetEx(communicate);

    }
```

warmUpTimes and the rest of "Times" are package-private, the error I get during test is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: jablonskijakub.intervaltraining.exceptions.WrongTimeSetEx

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

I'm not familiar with unit tests, I just read something about them and I can't find many examples. Sorry in advance for bad code.

@edit it's not even entering setTimes function
@edit2 Solved, I supposed my mocks don't make any sense, because I don't even pass them to function (function itself doesn't get any parameters), so I changed definition of setTimes and made it to get minutes and seconds in int and in test I passed only 0 as parameters. It worked, exception was thrown.

Comment: You should step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Charlesworth Well, I checked it now, it's not even entering this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I supposed my mocks don't make any sense, because I don't even pass them to function (function itself doesn't get any parameters), so I changed definition of setTimes and made it to get minutes and seconds in int and in test I passed only 0 as parameters. It worked, exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As you are throwing Exception when restTime is 0 according to your code & your test mocks restMinutes & restSeconds to return zero which in turn makes your restTime zero &  throws WrongTimeSetEx(communicate) where communicate is "communicate+="No time set for Rest Time". So make the following change in your test & it should work fine:-

```
when(restMinutes.getValue()).thenReturn(10);
when(restSeconds.getValue()).thenReturn(15);
when(rounds.getValue()).thenReturn(10);
```

Comment: But I'm expecting this exception to occur, that's the point of this test (at least I had that intention)